# Active Record: Adding "visit" counter on the model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I currently have a `Subscriber` model that takes in a "phone_number" and a "visit" attribute that is an integer. I want to set up a "check in" view form that will have a subscriber type in their phone_number and it will say if phone_number exists? add 1 to the visit attribute. So it will run a sql query and see if that number is in the database.

To be more clear I have to break the REST actions because the create action is already taken for the new subscribers. I'm pretty new to rails and I'm having a super hard time figuring this feature out. I'm curious if this is possible and how I should go about implementing this?

Here is my controller at the moment:

```
class SubscribersController < ApplicationController
 def index
  @subscriber = Subscriber.all
  end

  def new
    @subscriber = Subscriber.new
  end

  def create
    @subscriber = Subscriber.create(subscriber_params)
    if @subscriber.save
     flash[:success] = "Subscriber Has Been successfully Created"
     redirect_to new_subscriber_path(:subscriber)
    else
     render "new"
    end
  end

  def visit
  end

  private

  def subscriber_params
   params.require(:subscriber).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :phone_number)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something along those lines?

```
def visit
  subscriber = Subscriber.find_by_phone_number(params[:phone_number])
  if subscriber
    subscriber.visit += 1
    subscriber.save
  end
end
```

Make sure that the default value (via DB/Migration) for `visit` is set to 0.

You don't need to break REST style controller though. You can create another controller which does that check. For example something like:

```
class Subscriber::VisitController < ApplicationController
  def create
    # code here
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you for the help @pascal betz. Any suggestions what code should go in the create method in the sub controller?

Comment: same as in the ```visit``` method.

Comment: I'm new to most of these concepts, as I'm implementing your suggestion I keep running into errors my latest one is uninitialized constant Subscribers when I try to call visits/new in the url

Comment: We can not help without seeing code and error messages/stacktraces.